# SQL Web Traffic Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I came upon this question a couple of days back and couldn't find an optimal solution. We have a following table structure for storing some basic Web Traffic Logs of users who visit a particular website.

```
Table name:   [tblWebtraffic]  
Columns:      Id,IPAddress,PageName,Date
```

I want a single query(i.e single Select statement) to query out. The total visits and total unique visitors (based on IPAddress) and  total unique Pages that have been visited over the last 60 days.

PS:This is my first question in this site so forgive me if there are some details missing in the question. :)

EDIT: I am using a SQL Server Database.

Comment: Also missing is your attempt to solve this query.  Have you tried something yet?  Also, you labelled with incompatible databases.  Which database are you actually using?

Comment: Probably you don't have enough columns in order to get all the data you need.

Comment: Yes i have actually tried solving it,but in vain.I kinda solved it using multiple select queries all blocked inside a outer Select but i think there may be a better way to do it,Hence asking the experts

Comment: *"I am using a SQL Database."* -- which one? [tag:mysql] or [tag:sql-server]? They are different products produced by different companies; they implement SQL in slightly different ways, using different syntax details. Please tag your question correctly. SQL is just a language and there are dozens of products that implements it.

Comment: @Nurzhan all the relevant  columns are present,what do you suggest.

Comment: @axiac  A solution on any would be fine,I just need to know the logic

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT pageName, count(*) AS pageHits FROM tblWebtraffic GROUP BY pageName
```

will give you hits per page, a slight alteration will give unique page hits

```
SELECT pageName, count(DISTINCT ipAddress) AS uniquePageHits FROM tblWebtraffic GROUP BY pageName
```

of course, removing the group by on pagename will give you the entire site hits

```
SELECT count(*) AS siteHits FROM tblWebtraffic

SELECT count(DISTINCT ipAddress) uniqueSiteHits FROM tblWebtraffic
```

PS: my first attempt at answer, so if anything missing please let me know :)

edit: these will work on MS SQLServer Transact SQL .. MySQL I'm less familiar with but I just tried out SELECT count(Distinct fieldname) and it worked
edit2: thanks for the edits - the code formatting looks great

edit3: answering the question :)

`SELECT count(*) AS siteHits, count(DISTINCT ipAddress) AS uniqueSiteHits, count(DISTINCT pageName) AS uniquePages FROM tblWebtraffic WHERE DATEDIFF(d, [Date], getDate()) <= 60`

Comment: How do you show all the above using 1 single **SELECT** ,You have used 3 selects.I need to do it using only 1

Comment: My bad - you may combine these to get what you wish - but I'll do the right thing and answer the question :)

Comment: sorry - enter makes a new comment, shift enter new line

SELECT count(*) AS siteHits, count(DISTINCT ipAddress) AS uniqueSiteHits, count(DISTINCT pageName) AS uniquePages FROM tblWebtraffic WHERE DATEDIFF(d, [Date], getDate()) <= 60

Comment: `SELECT count(*) AS siteHits, count(DISTINCT ipAddress) AS uniqueSiteHits, count(DISTINCT pageName) AS uniquePages FROM tblWebtraffic WHERE DATEDIFF(d, [Date], getDate()) <= 60`